# How to sum a List[(Char,Int)] into a Map[Char,Int] in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I've got list of pairs:

```
List(('a',3),('b',3),('a',1))
```

and I would like to transform it by grouping by _1 and summing _2. The result should be like

```
Map('a'->4, 'b' -> 3)
```

I very new to Scala so please be kind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More direct version. We fold over the list, using a Map as the accumulator. The `withDefaultValue` means we don't have to test if we have the entry in the map already.

```
val xs =  List(('a',3),('b',3),('a',1))

xs.foldLeft(Map[Char, Int]() withDefaultValue 0)
           {case (m, (c, i)) => m updated (c,m(c)+i)}

//> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(a -> 4, b -> 3)
```

Comment: Ok, one question: when I copy your code directly to the worksheet it works, but when I do that: `List(('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('a', 1)) foldLeft(Map[Char, Int]() withDefaultValue 0) {case (m, (c, i)) => m updated (c,m(c)+i)}` it gives me an error saying that the `updated`: cannot resolve symbol. It is ok when I put the `.` between List(......).foldLeft(.......) but without it the compiler has issues.

Comment: Precedence issue, I think. Parens around the `(list foldleft Map...)` also fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
```

which can be written as

```
list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues { tuples => 
  val ints = tuples.map { case (c, i) => i }
  ints.sum
}
```

Comment: This is probably the simplest way to do it, but it is going to create a bunch of extraneous `Lists`, as well as require an additional iteration through the values associated with each key to obtain the sums.

Comment: @JasonLenderman what do you propose? `view`? I'm learning as well.

Comment: appending `.view` to `list` produces the same output and spawns  `SeqView*`s in the process which I think are lightweight.

Comment: Just to be clear, `mapValues` actually always creates a view.  It's one of the dangers of using `mapValues` that's not obvious from the name.

Comment: The issue isn't `view`. The problem happens at `groupBy` which creates a bunch of (unnecessary) `Lists`. The sum of a list can be computed in a streaming fashion, so there's no reason for those lists to be created in the first place. This is basically the same issue as `groupBy` followed by a `reduce` versus `reduceByKey` in Spark. For efficiency you always want to do the latter.